# rigidbody.velocity sudden freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity

I am new to unity..I am facing a problem with a moved object. I assign the gameObject a velocity but when it reaches a specific position ( 23,14, -750), the gameobject freezes. I can't know why. Sometimes it object continues moving and other times it suddenly stops. What's going wrong ? Thank you

```
    {
            if (transform.localPosition.z <= -760) {
                    gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }
            gameObject.rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, -speed);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want the object to freeze. I just want it to continue moving. But sometimes it freezes at specific position

Comment: Then why are you setting the object inactive in the condition above?

Comment: when it reaches 760 position.z I want it to be inactive to start again from its initial position but the problem is that it is freezing before reaching 760.

Comment: LearnCocos2D [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757780/rigidbody-velocity-sudden-freeze/24758915#comment38413910_24758213) what is your problem. Don't disable your object in Update function. When it is set as inactive, rest of the code won't be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an object to inactive, it will "freeze":

```
 if (transform.localPosition.z <= -760) {
     gameObject.SetActive (false);
 }
```

Not sure what you expect SetActive(false) to do but it has the result of stopping all logic including position updates and collision for the particular game object.

Comment: Thats right but I call the SetActive when reaching 760. but my object is freezing before reaching this value. Its freezing at 750.

Comment: How do you check the position? If you log this in Update for instance it may simply not perform the Update method after it has stopped so the last log will remain 750. It's close enough to assume that the object is no longer active. You may want to log it when the SetActive line runs.

Comment: actually this syntax is in the Update Method. u think thats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So don't make your object inactive. Save your initial position in Vector3.

```
 Vector3 initPosition = gameObject.rigidbody.position;
```

and set this value in your condition

```
if (transform.localPosition.z <= -760) {
 gameObject.rigidbody.position = initPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might fix the issue, when you are only providing the velocity, it freezes after sometime inevitably.  The trick to keep the velocity on you must add the velocity with Time.deltatime

This will keep the rigidbody updated and the velocity wont stop.

```
{
        if (transform.localPosition.z <= -760) {
                gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
        gameObject.rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, -speed+Time.deltatime);

}
```